# deleting entries in a dictionary based on a condition

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with names as key and (age, Date of Birth) tuple as the value for those keys. E.g.

```
dict = {'Adam' : (10, '2002-08-13'),
        'Eve'  : (40, '1972-08-13')}
```

I want to delete all the keys which have age > 30 for their age in value tuple, how can I do that? I am accessing age of each key using `dict[name][0]` where dict is my dictionary.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The usual way is to create a new dictionary containing only the items you want to keep:

```
new_data = {k: v for k, v in data.items() if v[0] <= 30}
```

If you need to change the original dictionary in place, you can use a `for`-loop:

```
for k, v in list(data.items()):
    if v[0] > 30:
        del data[k]
```

Note that `list(data.items())` creates a shallow copy of the items of the dictionary, i.e. a new list containing references to all keys and values, so it's safe to modify the original dict inside the loop.

Comment: I want to keep the entries with age <= 30 in the same dictionary. I don't want to write them in different dictionary.

Comment: @JustinCarrey: Is there a particular reason for this?  (There are legitimate reasons; I'm just curious.)

Comment: The actual program operates on different keys and values. But the function is same. So, to make it simple, i used names as keys and (age, DOB) as value.

Comment: @JustinCarrey: I don't understand how this is a reason to modify the original dictionary in place rather than creating a new one.

Comment: I should perform this operation from time to time(every 15 minutes or so). It is not productive to create new one each time. So, i chose in place dictionary.

Comment: @JustinCarrey: Since only pointers are copied, creating a new dictionary is as efficient as changing the old one in place.  In this case, I would even expect that it is the more efficient solution.  The `for` loop needs to copy pointers to *all* items to a list first, while the dictionary comprehension only copies the pointers that we want to keep.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I need to do this to use memory efficiently. I have a HUGE dictionary and I can't afford to make a copy of it. Do you think there is a way?

Comment: @navidoo: This creates only a shallow copy of the dictionary, so you probably can't get much more memory-efficient.  However, filtering dictionaries in memory that hardly fit seems like a questionable thing to do in the first place.

Comment: Is it safe to modify a dict that is currently being iterated (as in the answers given `for` loop)

Comment: @Dev No, it's not safe to modify a dictionary that is being iterated over. That's not what the code in this answer is doing though; `data.items()` in Ptyhon 2 or `list(data.items())` in Python 3 create a list of the items in the dictionary, and then iterate that new list, rather than the original dictionary. (I'll remove the Python 2 bits from this answer – I guess they are no longer relevant.)